# Asymptotic Notation: Finding two constants such that n >= n0

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

Here is an asymptotic notation problem:

Let g(n) = 27n^2 + 18n and let f(n) = 0.5n^2 − 100. Find positive constants n0, c1 and c2 such that c1f(n) ≤ g(n) ≤ c2f(n) for all n ≥ n0.

Is this solving for theta? Do I prove 27n^2 + 18n = Ω(0.5n^2 − 100) and then prove (27n^2 + 18n) = O(0.5n^2 − 100)?

In that case wouldn't c1 and c2 be 1 and 56 respectively, and n0 would be the higher of the two n0 that I find?

Comment: Might as well just try n0 = 1000000, c1=1/1000000, c2=1000000.  Yup, that works.

Comment: *"In that case wouldn't c1 and c2 be 1 and 56 respectively, and n0 would be the higher of the two n0 that I find?"* Your logic is pretty good, but choosing c2 = 56 is cutting it a bit close. Remember g(n) has an extra 18n in it, and f(n) has a -100. Better allow yourself some margin and take at least c2 = 60, or even c2 = 100 for good measure, or c2 = 1000000 like MattTimmermans suggests. The bigger c2, the less annoyed you'll be by these +18n and -100.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions. We just need to fiddle with algebra to find one.

The first thing to note is that both g and f are positive for all n≥15. In particular, g(15) = 6345, f(15) = 12.5. (All smaller values of n make f<0.) This implies n0=15 might work fine as well as any larger value.

Next note g'(n) = 54n + 18 and f'(n) = n.

Since f(15) < g(15) and f'(n) < g'(n) for all n >= 15, choose c1 = 1.

Proof that this is a good choice:

0.5n^2 − 100 ≤ 27n^2 + 18n <=> 26.5n^2 + 18n + 100 ≥ 0

...obviously true for all n≥15.

What about c2? First, we want c2*f(n) to grow at least as fast as g: c2f'(n)≥g'(n), or c2*n ≥ 54n + 18 for n ≥ 15. So choose c2 ≥ 56, which obviously makes this true.

Unfortunately, c2=56 doesn't quite work with n0 = 15. There's the other criterion to meet: c2*f(15)≥g(15).  For that, 56 isn't big enough: 56*f(15) is only 700; g(15) is much bigger.

It turns out by substitution in the relation above and a bit more algebra that c2 = 508 does the trick.

Proof:

27n^2 + 18n ≤ 508 * (0.5n^2 − 100)
  <=> 27n^2 + 18n ≤ 254n^2 − 50800
  <=> 227n^2 - 18n - 50800 ≥ 0

At n=15, this is true by simple substitution. For all bigger values of n, note the lhs derivative 454n - 18 is positive for all n≥15, so the function is also non-decreasing over that domain. That makes the relation true as well.

To summarize, we've shown that **n0=15, c1=1, and c2=508** is one solution.